# Using AUTO_INCREMENT with other value MYSQL generated, duplicate rows generated. How to replace id with my values?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I am replacing auto_increment id with my own(of sequential and auto generated from a base number).   I used `ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 701`.
MySQL produced duplicates(ones with auto generated from "1" and (another sets from "701.   Please see the scripts as below:   Kindly help me to avoid MYSQL generated rows.   Much obliged.

```
use login_db;
show databases;
CREATE TABLE logtable
(
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, accountno char(8) not null, PRIMARY    KEY      (id),
username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
password varchar(20),
firstname varchar(8),
lastname varchar(8),
email varchar(30)
);
alter table logtable AUTO_INCREMENT = 701;
insert into logtable (username,password,firstname,lastname,email) values      
('kamitrust','rust8115','john','lee','support@poosung.com');
Select  * from logtable;
insert into logtable (username,password,firstname,lastname,email) values   ('pinktop','winston19','jeff','kim','aol@poosung.com');
Select  * from logtable;
```

The result from executing the script above:

```
# id, accountno, username, password, firstname, lastname, email
'1', '', 'kamitrust', 'rust8115', 'john', 'lee', 'support@poosung.com'
'2', '', 'pinktop', 'winston19', 'jeff', 'kim', 'aol@poosung.com'
'701', '', 'kamitrust', 'rust8115', 'john', 'lee', 'support@poosung.com'
'702', '', 'pinktop', 'winston19', 'jeff', 'kim', 'aol@poosung.com'
```

Comment: What happens if you put `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS logtable` immediately before `CREATE TABLE logtable ...`?  It looks to me like your logtable already existed and had two rows in it before you ran your `ALTER TABLE` statement.

Comment: Its better to keep your ID filed unique. If you want its better to create another field and perform your increment in that field by yourself.

Comment: @Ollie Jones, thanks for your observation, you are right.   I dropped the table and re-executed the same.   The duplicates were gone, finding that